# One to one correspondence between sets and cartesian product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a question. If there is a one-to-one correspondence between two sets when the cartesian product is found, does this include all the possible pairs between the elements of the two sets?

I think the answer is TRUE because for example if I have these sets: $A$: $\{x,y,z\}$ and $B$: $\{a,b,c\}$. They are one-to-one, $x$ is assigned to $a$, $y$ is assigned to $b$, and $z$ is assigned to $c$.

Then the cartesian product $A × B =\{(x,a),(x,b),(x,c),(y,a),(y,b),(y,c),(z,a),(z,b),(z,c)\}$.

Or because they are one-to-one the cartesian product is limited to $A × B = {(x,a),(y,b),(z,c)}$?

I'm bit confused here.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: The former is the correct [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product); the number of elements in the Cartesian product of two sets is the product of the numbers of elements of the sets; for example $A\times A$ would be $\{(x,x),(x,y),(x,z),(y,x),(y,y),(y,z),(z,x),(z,y),(z,z)\}$

Comment: Hi. Regardless of whether or not the sets are one-to-one? 
So the answer is true? The cartesian product of two one-to-one sets are the possible pairs between elements of the two sets?

Comment: Yes, in this context, it doesn't matter whether the sets are equinumerous (have the same cardinality) or not

Comment: Note that the bijective function between $A$ and $B$ is not unique; you could assign $x$ to $b$, $y$ to $c$, and $z$ to $a$

Comment: ok. thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets $A$ and $B$ has all ordered pairs $(u,d)$ where $u\in A$ and $d\in B$, whether or not $A$ and $B$ are equinumerous.  The number of elements in the Cartesian product of two sets is the product of the numbers of elements of the sets.  Thus, in your example, your first ("unlimited") description of $A\times B$ is the correct one.